# Declaring js libraries in index.html just load 1 time in reactjs

Tags: jquery, reactjs, redux

I have a problem and hope people suggest me some solutions.
  I am using Reactjs that has some js (jquery) libraries declared in index.html and all functions only run if I refresh the page. 
  Now I want when I change the route, the functions in the js library will run again. I tried to use $ from 'jquery' in my container to call tge libraries really hard to export because it has many errors. 
 Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need JQ... It doesn't do anything that React can not... In general, all libs that directly manipulate the DOM are not 'React friendly'....

Answer (score 0):

The index file only gets loaded on page load in react. If you want something to be called when routes get changed you need to configure that through the router you are using. If you are using react-router then you can use `history.listen()` [documentation here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history).